# Angular2 - Only Allow Alpha Characters TO Be Entered In An Input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am very new to `Angular2` and cant seem to find my answer anywhere.  I have an `input` (as show below) but I only want it to allow the following:

- A-Z
- a-z
- '
- -
- [SPACE]

I have no idea on how to do this. I have tried `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"`, `pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"` and `ng-pattern-restrict="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"`.

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="details.firstName" placeholder="First name(s)" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/">
    </md-input-container>
</td>
```

Ideally if a user enters a numeric character, I'd ether like it to be removed by itself or just not be allowed (not displayed) in the field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My fix was to do it in my component

```
firstName: ['', Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')],
```

Comment: Note that this only works for [Reactive Froms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 18):

Angular Reactive Form Validation - To accept only alphabets and space.

```
firstName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(50),
          Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')
        ]
      ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use following to make pattern work

```
<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="details.firstName" placeholder="First name(s)" [pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z \-\']$'">
```

Comment: Thanks but this is causing the following error: `Parser Error: Unexpected token ']' at column 14 in ['^[a-zA-Z \-']$'] in ng:///AppModule/PersonalDetailsComponent.html@12:91 ("tainer>
                <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="details.firstName" placeholder="First name(s)" [ERROR ->][pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z \-']$'">
            </md-input-container>
        </td>`

Comment: I have used the update but I am still able to enter 0-9 in the field.

Answer (score -2):

You can use following directive that allow to type strings which pass arbitrary regexp

```js
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[allowedRegExp]'})
export class AllowedRegExpDirective {
    
  @Input() allowedRegExp: string;
  
  @HostListener('keydown',['$event']) onKeyDown(event: any) {
    let k=event.target.value + event.key;

    if(['ArrowLeft','ArrowRight','ArrowUp','ArroDown','Backspace','Tab','Alt'
       'Shift','Control','Enter','Delete','Meta'].includes(event.key)) return;

    let re = new RegExp(this.allowedRegExp);
        
    if(!re.test(k)) event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

example usage: 0-5 characters from your question

```
<input [allowedRegExp]="'^[a-zA-Z '-]{0,5}$'" type="text" ... >
```

Answer (score -5):

Use this :

`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"`

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted answer - it is AngularJS way, not Angular which was required.

Comment: Yes this is not an Angular2+ solution

Comment: here you can't enter a space. then it is invalid